# Crash when trying to create a simple list

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview, simpleadapter

I am trying to generate a simple list using showArticles method and the I am encountering a crash, I have tried numerous solution but it seems that I am calling some system method before onCreate, I am unable to see my mistake in the code presented below:

```
public class ArticleListActivity extends ListActivity {
    Context context;
    ListView lv;

    private static class ArticleListLoadingCallback implements Handler.Callback {
        private ListActivity activity;
        private ArticleListManager articleListManager;

        public ArticleListLoadingCallback(ListActivity activity,
                ArticleListManager articleListManager) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.articleListManager = articleListManager;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
            throw new MethodNotYetImplementedException();
        }
    }

    private ArticleListManager articleListManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_list);

        articleListManager = new ArticleListManager(ArticleListActivity.this,
                this.context);
        /*articleListManager.fetchArticles(new Handler(
                new ArticleListLoadingCallback(this, articleListManager)));*/

       showArticles();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Article article = (Article) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ArticleDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("article", article);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void showArticles() {


        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
            "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
            "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
          list.add(values[i]);
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_article_list,list));

        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

My XML goes as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/myProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

I am getting the following Crash/Error:

```
> 12-15 21:03:53.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1989): FATAL EXCEPTION:
> Thread-156 12-15 21:03:53.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to
> Activities before onCreate() 12-15 21:03:53.581:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1989):   at
> android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4410) 12-15
> 21:03:53.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at
> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310) 12-15
> 21:03:53.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at
> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
```

Any Suggestions would be greatly appreciated, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: r u want to create simple list view

Comment: did you tried calling ArticleListLoadingCallback and handlemessage method in onCreate() or after onCreate() ?

Comment: @Darkie I did try but the result is very similar, at this point getting the list to populate is my goal

Comment: @MRMido if you are trying to populate the listview then you are doing it wrong. try this tutorial this might help you ...
http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/populating-listview-with-arraylist.html